# PHP assoiative Array with almost Similar Keys

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I have an associative array

```
array(
    'item_name1' => 'PCC',
    'item_name2' => 'ext',
    'item_number1' => '060716113223-13555',
    'item_number2' => '49101220160607-25222)',
)
```

What i Want to do is catch all the  array keys where the key name has similarities

for example
i want to echo out item_name (it should get both item_name1 & item_name2)  but i require it in a loop (foreach/for) so that i can send  within the loop the details to my database for each set of values

Thanks For the help

Comment: my array has  item_name1 and item_name2 i want to echo it out in a loop withouth  using arrayname['item_name1'];

Comment: you have to provide more details  like what you actually want to achieve  through your expected outcome and what you have tried so for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data model seems to use numeric suffixes as a replacement for arrays so I'll assume that *key name has similarities* is an overestimated problem statement and you merely want to fix that.

The obvious tool is regular expressions:

```
$original_data = array(
    'item_name1' => 'PCC',
    'item_name2' => 'ext',
    'item_number1' => '060716113223-13555',
    'item_number2' => '49101220160607-25222)',
);

$redacted_data = array();
foreach ($original_data as $key => $row) {
    if (preg_match('/^(.+)(\d+)$/u', $key, $matches)) {
        $redacted_data[$matches[1]][$matches[2]] = $row;
    } else {
        $redacted_data[$key][] = $row;
    }
}
var_dump($redacted_data);
```

It should be easy to tweak for your exact needs.

I can't figure out what the *i require it in a loop (foreach/for)* requirement means but you can loop the resulting array as any other array:

```
foreach ($redacted_data as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $kk => $vv) {
        printf("(%s,%s) = %s\n", $k, $kk, $vv);
    }
}
```

Comment: the array got combined like this which seem perfect  array( [item_name] => Array ( [1] => Potrait Color Correction [2] => Extraction )

Comment: That's different data that you shared. Whatever, make sure you actually understand the code and don't forget to add your own safety checks (for instance, you may not want to overwrite existing keys).

Comment: the array got combined like this which seem perfect                                  `code`array( [item_name] => Array ( [1] => PCC [2] => Ext )[item_number] => Array ( [1] => 060716113223-13555 [2] => 49101220160607-25222 )) whcih seems now organized          Now In Order To Print both of them                                      foreach ($redacted_data['item_name'] as $abc => $val) {
   foreach ($redacted_data['item_number'] as $xyz => $valu) {
    echo $val.'<br>';echo $valu;
  }
 }`code`

Comment: thats exacty what i was gonna aks to prevent the values from replicating  Potrait Color Correction
060716113223-13555Potrait Color Correction
49101220160607-25222Extraction
060716113223-13555Extraction
49101220160607-25222  like this

Comment: I used this to echo out the values without repetition   but if there is a better way to do it could you suggest      ` $arr=array();
  foreach ($redacted_data['item_name'] as $abc => $val) {
   foreach ($redacted_data['item_number'] as $xyz => $valu) {
    
     if(!in_array($val, $arr)){
    echo $val."  ";echo $valu;
   }
     $arr[]=$val;
     $arr[]=$valu;
     
  } 
 } `

Answer (score 1):

Use the funtion array_keys

```
$allKeys = array_keys($yourArray);
$amountKeys = count($allKeys);
```

Unless you do not provide more code this will give you all the keys of `$yourArray`
[Reference - array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

To get all the similar keys you can use this function [similar-text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)

Since I do not know how "similar" a key can be I would suggest you to test out different values and find a degree that matches your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$items=[];
$itemsNumbers=[];
foreach($itemarr as $key=> $val)
{
    $itempos = strpos("item_name", $key);
    if ($pos !== false) 
        $items[]=$val;
    $numberpos = strpos("item_number", $key);
    if ($numberpos !== false) 
        $itemsNumbers[]=$val;

}

?>
Note: here $itemarr is your input array
```

$items you will get list of item names and  $itemsNumbers you will get  list of itemsNumbers